# How prevent show kendo tooltip by some condition?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, tooltip

How prevent show kendo tooltip by some condition? I have tried use k-filter but it doesn't work.

```
    <span class="avatarWrapper showTooltip" 
ng-style="vm.avatarStyle" 
k-filter="'.showTooltip'"  
ng-class="{'showTooltip': !vm.isReadOnly}"  
k-callout="false" 
k-show="vm.showTooltip" 
kendo-tooltip 
k-content="vm.entityTooltip()">
        </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can achieve that using `filter` parameter:

```
<div id="container">
    <span class="showTooltip" k-...></span>
</div>
```

Wrap your tooltip target within a container and start the tooltip in this container filtering by `.showTooltip.show`. Then you just add or remove the `.show` class whatever you like to *enable* or *disable* it. Check the below demo to see it working:

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/IBAHI)